# Types of property 'render' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, quill

I am using ReactQuill as a component, but I am facing this error while using Typescript. Any suggestions for mitigation

> JSX element type 'ReactQuill' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
>   Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
>   Type '() => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '{ (): false | Element | null; (): ReactNode; }'.
>   Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
>   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.`

[Issue on Typescript Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24898)

Comment: Please can you share a minimal code example that demonstrates the error?

Comment: `<ReactQuill/>` is what is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have given the type as `() => ReactNode` somewhere, change that to `Element`